# Sample implementation of Merkle Block Retrieval not working

Tags: bitcoin-core

This is the code from https://developer.bitcoin.org/examples/p2p_networking.html on how to retrieve a merkle block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep
from hashlib import sha256
import struct
import sys

network_string = "f9beb4d9".decode("hex")  # Mainnet

def send(msg,payload):
    ## Command is ASCII text, null padded to 12 bytes
    command = msg + ( ( 12 - len(msg) ) * "\00" )

    ## Payload length is a uint32_t
    payload_raw = payload.decode("hex")
    payload_len = struct.pack("I", len(payload_raw))

    ## Checksum is first 4 bytes of SHA256(SHA256(<payload>))
    checksum = sha256(sha256(payload_raw).digest()).digest()[:4]

    sys.stdout.write(
        network_string
        + command
        + payload_len
        + checksum
        + payload_raw
    )
    sys.stdout.flush()

## Create a version message
send("version",
      "71110100" # ........................ Protocol Version: 70001
    + "0000000000000000" # ................ Services: Headers Only (SPV)
    + "c6925e5400000000" # ................ Time: 1415484102
    + "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    + "0000ffff7f000001208d" # ............ Receiver IP Address/Port
    + "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    + "0000ffff7f000001208d" # ............ Sender IP Address/Port
    + "0000000000000000" # ................ Nonce (not used here)
    + "1b" # .............................. Bytes in version string
    + "2f426974636f696e2e6f726720457861"
    + "6d706c653a302e392e332f" # .......... Version string
    + "93050500" # ........................ Starting block height: 329107
    + "00" # .............................. Relay transactions: false
)

sleep(1)
send("verack", "")
send("filterload",
      "02"  # ........ Filter bytes: 2
    + "b50f" # ....... Filter: 1010 1101 1111 0000
    + "0b000000" # ... nHashFuncs: 11
    + "00000000" # ... nTweak: 0/none
    + "00" # ......... nFlags: BLOOM_UPDATE_NONE
)
send("getdata",
      "01" # ................................. Number of inventories: 1
    + "03000000" # ........................... Inventory type: filtered block
    + "a4deb66c0d726b0aefb03ed51be407fb"
    + "ad7331c6e8f9eef231b7000000000000" # ... Block header hash
)
```

But the code above doesn't run, thus I made some amendments (if not the error that '*bytes can't concat to strings*' will be displayed) to this part:

```
sys.stdout.write(
    str(network_string)
    + command
    + str(payload_len)
    + str(checksum)
    + str(payload_raw)
)
```

Thereafter, I ran `-bitcoind daemon` before piping the script to Unix netcat command:

```
# Connect to the Bitcoin Core peer running on localhost
python get-merkle.py | nc localhost 8333 | hd
```

But to no response.

The expected response is:

```
7f16c5962e8bd963659c793ce370d95f
093bc7e367117b3c30c1f8fdd0d97287 ... Merkle root

07000000 ........................... Transaction count: 7
04 ................................. Hash count: 4

3612262624047ee87660be1a707519a4
43b1c1ce3d248cbfc6c15870f6c5daa2 ... Hash #1
019f5b01d4195ecbc9398fbf3c3b1fa9
bb3183301d7a1fb3bd174fcfa40a2b65 ... Hash #2
41ed70551dd7e841883ab8f0b16bf041
76b7d1480e4f0af9f3d4c3595768d068 ... Hash #3
20d2a7bc994987302e5b1ac80fc425fe
25f8b63169ea78e68fbaaefa59379bbf ... Hash #4

01 ................................. Flag bytes: 1
1d ................................. Flags: 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Are you connected to a node that has BIP37 enabled? In Bitcoin Core it is off by default, unless started with `-peerbloomfilters`. See BIP111 for details.

Comment: Ok. It still doesn’t work even after setting -peerbloomfilters=1.

Comment: Do you receive a "version" message?

Comment: Nope no message at all.

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong before sending the filter commands.